# Islam position of the use of "Allah" word by non-Muslims as a synonym to God

Tags: allah, terminology

This is because I read today the news about Malaysia banning of a comic book using the word "Allah" to describe its hero. ([Al Jazeera](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/asia-pacific/2014/03/malaysia-bans-comic-book-using-allah-20143752451298126.html))

For me I feel that using it in such context is defaming to Islam, as it diverges Allah meaning to just a synonym word for God. Some argues that Christians use it, and it is true, but they usually use it as "Allah the Father" to distinguish it from Islamic concept of Allah.

Another thing is that Allah implies Islam most of the time, so when you one hears the word Allah, Islam what comes to mind first, and its different from when one is using God, as it refers to a deity or a supreme creature of any religion.

**Is there a discussion between scholars on this matter or similar things happening somewhere else? And what is Islam position on this matter?**

Answer (score 2):

Although it is by and large a civil issue, ALLAH **does not** mean god. [ILAH](http://translate.google.com/#en/ar/god) is the word that is synonymous to god. The comic character in the context is Ultraman, who, if is worth deifying, deserves being called  *ILAH*, not *ALLAH*. Now you re-consider the situation.

- *What about scholarly talk on this issue?*
  -- I did not find any article on the issue of banning comics yet. But regarding Malaysia banning Christians from using the world Allah, there has been a open letter conversation between [Nehali](http://www.themalaysianinsider.com/sideviews/article/brahma-instead-of-allah-nehali) and [Abdullah Ismail](http://www.themalaysianinsider.com/sideviews/article/view-the-allah-controversy-in-context-abdullah-ismail).
- *what is Islam position on this matter?*
  Quran calls Allah in verse [114:3](http://quran.com/114/3)

  > The God of mankind

  So **HE** can be called ALLAH by anyone, But a comic character, **NO**. Because

  > Nor is there to Him any equivalent [[112:4](http://quran.com/112/4)]

Comment: ilah:on = a God in Arabic. Allah is coming from ilah:on (وَإِلَٰهُكُمْ إِلَٰهٌ وَاحِدٌ ۖ) Allah is the definite article of the word ilah, meaning The God. In arabic, it more means The (only) God....  2:255: The (only) God, there is no god except He. There are no evidence to make it personal, that it is His personal name "Allah". One should consider that the Quran is in Arabic, and that Allah is in Arabic and it means The God. There are other nations before Islam, with other languages, calling God by other names. Did He change name with the Quran? The message of the Quran is clear. ONE God!