# Can Christians use the word Allah according to Quran?

Tags: allah, terminology

[Christians in Malaysia were fighting in court](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-27970565) to use the word "Allah". According to Quran, it seems that [one shouldn't use Allah to describe a comic book character](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/11704/4503).

But I have questions on that specific Quran verse that is used to forbid describing a comic book character with the word Allah:

> Nor is there to Him any equivalent [[112:4](http://quran.com/112/4)]

Judging from the literal reading the verse, this verse also forbids the use of Allah on any God, be it Christian God, or Jewish God, because all these religions are not exactly worshiping the same God. Especially Christian God because Christian God is a trinity which includes Jesus ( Nabi Musa), so if Christians use Allah, that means Jesus is also Allah, which is wrong.

Am I right on this?

Comment: I think the verse you have quoted is referring to the attribute, the essence, the existence and the reality of what Allah actually is. Meaning nothing can compare infront of Allah. All existance and creation vanishes/burns away in the face of Allah's existance. So in a sense you are right, that in reality Allah is the being that is pure from all limitations the other religions have placed upon Allah. But then again, Allah is just as much God to the Muslims as he is to the christians, jews, hindus, athiest,etc... Allah is RABAL-ALAMEEN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even Quran quotes Christians using the word 'Allah'.

> But the Jews and the Christians say, "We are the children of **Allah** and
>   His beloved." [Quran 5:18](http://quran.com/5/18)
>
> The Jews say, "Ezra is the son of Allah "; and the Christians say,
>   "The Messiah is the son of **Allah**." [Quran 9:30](http://quran.com/9/30)

Quran was not criticizing their using the word Allah but their beliefs about Allah (trinity, Jesus being son of Allah etc.)

Answer (score 0):

God has many names, about 99 names including( Allah, the almighty, the merciful.....) the Name Allah breaks into two parts in the Arabic language (Al-Ilah) which means god therfor the translation for Allah in English is God according to some internet sources, hopefully i am not committing a sin.
Another research i have done is comparing the names of god between Christianity, Islam, Judaism and i found out that they are a match, even in Christianity and Judaism God is not just called god there can be other names (the merciful, the almighty), Christians, Jews and Muslims worship the same god the trinity is a form of corruption to the christian religion, there is no other worthy of worship but god, jesus was a prophet not a god and god would not want you to worship jesus because he was sent with a message god does not have sons and saying so will lead to hell fire.

Comment: Aboudi, would you like to explain how your answer really answers my question?

Comment: If my understanding is correct you mentioned that in the three religions (Judasim, Christianity and islam) you said that there are Gods for each where one according to their religion will worship that god, we as Muslims believe that god the only has sent out a message through prophets to only worship him in these religions which explains why i mentioned the same names of god in those three relegions and

Comment: then i reffered to the trinity as a form of corruption in the christian religion because Jesus him self did not say i am the son of god and i will die for your sins, so i would say that we worship the same god in the three religions, not all Christians beleive in the trinity and frequently question it so you cant generalise and say all Christians believe in the trinity.

Comment: and yes you are correct Jesus is not also Allah, like i said Jesus was a prophet sent with a message from allah, let me know if my answer helps!

Comment: in the Arabic version of the bible the name allah is frequently mentioned so yes Christians can use the name allah as long as it does not refer to the trinity

Answer (score 0):

Christian Jewish and Islamic, and other monotheistic religions have same God. So the word Allah can be used there too.

> "Verily, Allah! He is my Lord (God) and your Lord (God). So worship
>   Him (Alone). This is the (only) Straight Path (i.e. Allah's religion
>   of true Islamic Monotheism)."45:64
>
> And do not argue with the People of the Scripture except in a way that
>   is best, except for those who commit injustice among them, and say,
>   "We believe in that which has been revealed to us and revealed to you.
>   And our God and your God is one; and we are Muslims [in submission] to
>   Him."29:46
>
> It befits not (the Majesty of) Allah that He should beget a son [this
>   refers to the slander of Christians against Allah, by saying that
>   'Iesa (Jesus) is the son of Allah]. Glorified (and Exalted be He above
>   all that they associate with Him). When He decrees a thing, He only
>   says to it, "Be!" and it is.19:35

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Arabic word for god is ilah and the name Allah comes from Al-Ilah, which means like The God, the only one, uncomparable one, creator of the worlds, sender of the prophets etc in the religion of Abraham's, Moses's, Jesus's, Mohammad's etc (peace be upon all of them). Its more like a private name than an adjective. Also The God in all these religions are the same god actually, just some Christians understand him wrong. We believe that Allah is not trinity, some Christians believe that he is. One of us is wrong, but any of these beliefs actually doesn't change Allah. We just believe different things about him. We are talking about the same God (apart from Zeus etc).

Secondly, I don't think there is a verse forbidding it and the one you gave is out of topic. Giving a child the name Mohammad doesn't make him a prophet and giving someone the name Allah doesn't make him The God. But why do want someone this apart from ignorance and insult?

All around the world, people are divided and hate each other, harm each other. Even if there is a verse from Qur'an, the ones who want to do this won't care because they are not Muslims, Muslims don't do that, because they know this is an insult. Also these people are unrespectful and unlogical people, because what will bring this action is clear and any non-Muslim also can realize that. Giving the name Allah to a person will have serious disastrous effects in the world. They will be seen unrespectful in the eyes of all Muslims. Also some radicals are probably going to kill them. Even if they are killed or not, the Islam will look like violent and intolerant in the eyes of the world. I don't think they want to die like this, I think they just don't care. But in the logical sense, this action will bring no good, but a lot of harm to both sides.

If they do that, should we try to harm them physically? No. This part is clear. But there is a reality. We can't stop all of the radicals. Remember the "movie of the Mohammad(puh)" issue. Some people get angry and killed some people of the American Embassy in Egypt. They were innocent about this issue, yet they were killed. This was wrong, but we can't bring them back.

Because of reality, until most of the Muslims would become educated enough to respond without violence, they shouldn't attack to Islam like this, or movies etc. This is dangerous to them also.